# What are the differences between Clang AST Matcher and AST Visitor?

Tags: c++, clang, abstract-syntax-tree, matcher, visitor-pattern

Two powerful ways to open the box of Clang. What should I consider when deciding to use one over the other?

Clang website offers some old [tutorial](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/RAVFrontendAction.html) on how to use `RecursiveASTVisitor` to find a `Decl` AST node, as well as some new [tutorial](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchersTutorial.html) on how to use `ASTMatcher`to find some `for` stmt. In this context, there is much overlap on what they can achieve.

For simple tasks as mentioned above, I find `ASTMatcher` more convenient, as the used predicate is short and easy to read. However, for more complex tasks such as source-to-source transformations, where analysis is needed for the whole translation unit. Implementing the Visitor functions seems a better approach. Because the predicates in my `ASTMatcher` tend to get lengthy and difficult to understand. Maybe there is an efficient way to use `ASTMatcher` with lang and complex predicates. I appreciate any advice on this. Since `ASTMatcher` was introduced later, is it intend to replace the old `AST Visitor` method?

Answer (score 1):

Good question. Sometimes matchers are infeasible for a type of pattern that involves variable number of AST nodes and complexity in between two patterns that you're looking for. Here's an example:

For example, matching any class with the name `Foo`, and if all of its methods have a variable `y` in it. The AST would look something like:

```
|-CXXRecordDecl 0x563295d82010 <sandbox/class.cpp:1:1, line:6:1> line:1:7 class Foo definition
...
| |-CXXRecordDecl 0x563295d82128 <col:1, col:7> col:7 implicit class Foo
| |-FieldDecl 0x563295d821d0 <line:2:5, col:9> col:9 x 'int'
| `-CXXMethodDecl 0x563295d82298 <line:3:5, line:5:5> line:3:10 bar 'void ()'
|   `-CompoundStmt 0x563295d823e8 <col:16, line:5:5>
|     `-DeclStmt 0x563295d823d0 <line:4:9, col:14>
|       `-VarDecl 0x563295d82368 <col:9, col:13> col:13 y 'int'
```

For a single function. As far as I know, there is no easy way to match ALL methoddecls and match a wildcard number of stmts until you get to a variable `y` in the definition. It would be in your best interest to use an AST visitor pattern for this.